# Recursive which ends itself

Tags: vb.net, recursion

I want to search within a room for rooms (I dont know how many rooms are in a room).

Then for each room in this room I want to search again if there are rooms in these rooms and so on (recursive).

But if a room depth level reaches X, it should stop/save OR if there are no more rooms. My code basically works but it overrides a room when there are more rooms in it.

So let's say a room A has two rooms Room 1 and Room 2. Then my function will work with Room 1 but ignores Room 2 and I don't know why.

```
    Private Class Room
    Public Name As String
    Public RoomCounter As Integer
End Class

Private Const _maxRooms As Integer = 2

Private Sub GetRoomsRecursive(pMatchString As String, pCurrentRound As Integer, pOriginalRoom As Room)

    Dim foundRooms As String = RoomsMatching(pMatchString)

    For Each s As String In foundRooms.Split(vbNewLine)
        If Not s.Contains(";") Then 'There are rooms in that room
            If pCurrentRound >= _maxRooms - 1 Then Continue For 'Don't search further

            If pOriginalRoom Is Nothing Then
                Dim tempRoom As New Room With {.Name = $"Room_{s}"}
                tempRoom.RoomCounter += 1
                GetRoomsRecursive(pMatchString, pCurrentRound + 1, tempRoom)
            Else
                If pOriginalRoom.RoomCounter = _maxRooms Then Continue For '
                pOriginalRoom.Name = $"Room_{s}" 'Override name
                pOriginalRoom.RoomCounter += 1
                GetRoomsRecursive(pMatchString, pCurrentRound + 1, pOriginalRoom)
                End If
            Else 'There are no more rooms
                 If pOriginalRoom Is Nothing Then
                    Dim tempRoom As New Room With {.Name = $"Room_{s}"}
                    tempRoom.RoomCounter += 1
                   'todo: save the room
                Else
                    If pOriginalRoom.RoomCounter = _maxRooms Then Continue For '
                    pOriginalRoom.Name = $"Room_{s}" 'Override name
                    pOriginalRoom.RoomCounter += 1
                    'todo: save the room
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: The difficulty is that I want to store the path's. So in the end I can see that RoomA->Room1->RoomZ and RoomA->Room2->RoomY

Comment: Using your current Class `Room`, with only `Name` and `RoomCounter` fields, how are you representing the **relationships** between the rooms?  You must be delimiting that information in the `Name` field somehow?  I would expect to see something more like `Public Rooms As New List(of Room)`, so you can literally have a link to each room within that room...thus facilitating an actual recursive algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.